# C++ linq-like library

Tags: c++, linq, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel

I want to implement something like C# Linq in C++

Currently only `select` and `where` is implemented, but others should be fairly easy if I can make a good structure.

The main concerns I have is I am not sure when to pass reference and when to pass value. Also how it works with different types (array type, lvalue, rvalue, const type, etc)

```
namespace linq {

    namespace detail
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct IteratorBase
        {
            virtual ~IteratorBase() {}

            virtual T operator *() const = 0;
            virtual IteratorBase & operator++() = 0; // prefix ++
            virtual bool operator==(const IteratorBase &other) const = 0;
            bool operator!=(const IteratorBase &other) const { return !(other == *this); }
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct Iterator : IteratorBase<T>
        {
            virtual std::unique_ptr<Iterator> copy() = 0;
        };

        template <typename T, typename InputIterator>
        struct IteratorImpl : Iterator<T>
        {
            IteratorImpl() : _it() {}
            IteratorImpl(const InputIterator &it) : _it(it) {}

            ~IteratorImpl() {}

            T operator *() const { return *_it; }
            IteratorBase<T> & operator++() { ++_it; return *this; };
            bool operator==(const IteratorBase<T> &other) const
            {
                const IteratorImpl *otherptr = dynamic_cast<const IteratorImpl *>(&other);
                if (otherptr) {
                    return _it == otherptr->_it;
                }
                return false;
            }

            std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T>> copy()
            {
                return std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T>>{ new IteratorImpl<T, InputIterator>(_it) };
            }

        private:
            InputIterator _it;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct IteratorWrapper : IteratorBase<T>
        {
            template <typename InputIterator>
            IteratorWrapper(const InputIterator &it) : _it(new IteratorImpl<T, InputIterator>(it)) {}
            IteratorWrapper(const IteratorWrapper &other) : _it(other._it->copy()) {}

            ~IteratorWrapper() {}

            T operator *() const { return *(*_it); }
            IteratorBase<T> & operator++() { ++(*_it); return *this; }
            bool operator==(const IteratorBase<T> &other) const {
                const IteratorWrapper *otherptr = dynamic_cast<const IteratorWrapper *>(&other);
                if (otherptr) {
                    return (*otherptr->_it) == (*_it);
                }
                return false;
            }
        private:
            const std::unique_ptr<Iterator<T>> _it;
        };

        template <typename T, typename U>
        struct SelectIterator
        {
            SelectIterator(const IteratorWrapper<T> &it, std::function<U(T)>func) : _it(it), _func(func) {}

            U operator *() const { return _func(*_it); }
            SelectIterator & operator++() { ++_it; return *this; }
            bool operator==(const SelectIterator &other) const { return _it == other._it; }

        private:
            IteratorWrapper<T> _it;
            std::function<U(T)> _func;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct WhereIterator
        {
            WhereIterator(const IteratorWrapper<T> &begin, const IteratorWrapper<T> &end, std::function<bool(T)>func) : _it(begin), _end(end), _func(func), _val()
            {
                validate();
            }

            WhereIterator(const IteratorWrapper<T> &end) : _it(end), _end(end), _func(), _val() {};

            T operator *() const { return _val; }
            WhereIterator & operator++() { ++_it; validate(); return *this; }
            bool operator==(const WhereIterator &other) const { return _it == other._it; }

        private:

            void validate()
            {
                if (_it != _end) {
                    _val = *_it;

                    while (_it != _end && !_func(_val)) {
                        ++_it;
                        _val = *_it;
                    }
                }
            }

            T _val;
            IteratorWrapper<T> _it;
            IteratorWrapper<T> _end;
            std::function<bool(T)> _func;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct Range
        {
            template <typename InputIterator>
            Range(const InputIterator &begin, const InputIterator &end)
            : _begin(begin), _end(end)
            {}

            IteratorWrapper<T> & begin() { return _begin; }
            IteratorWrapper<T> & end() { return _end; }

            template <typename Functor>
            auto select(Functor func) -> Range<decltype(func(T()))>
            {
                using ReturnType = decltype(func(T()));
                return { SelectIterator<T, ReturnType>(_begin, func), SelectIterator<T, ReturnType>(_end, func) };
            }

            Range where(std::function<bool(T)> func)
            {
                return { WhereIterator<T>(_begin, _end, func), WhereIterator<T>(_end) };
            }

        private:
            IteratorWrapper<T> _begin;
            IteratorWrapper<T> _end;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct ValueIterator
        {
            ValueIterator(T val) : _val(val) {}

            T operator *() const { return _val; }
            ValueIterator & operator++() { ++_val; return *this; }
            bool operator==(const ValueIterator &other) const { return _val == other._val; }

        private:
            T _val;
        };

    }

    using detail::Range;

    template <typename T>
    Range<T> range(T from, T end)
    {
        return { detail::ValueIterator<T>(from), detail::ValueIterator<T>(end) };
    }

    template <typename T>
    Range<T> range(T end)
    {
        return { detail::ValueIterator<T>(T()), detail::ValueIterator<T>(end) };
    }

    template <typename FromType>
    auto from(FromType f) -> Range<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(f))>::type>
    {
        return { std::begin(f), std::end(f) };
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto from(std::initializer_list<T> f) -> Range<T>
    {
        return { std::begin(f), std::end(f) };
    }
}
```

It can be used like this

```
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5}; // some iterable
    auto r =
    linq::from(vec)
    .where([](int i){ return i % 2;})
    .select([](int i){ return i * i;})
    ;

    for (auto obj : r)
    {
        std::cout << obj << "\n";
    }
}

{
    auto r =
    linq::range(1, 30)
    .where([](int i){ return i % 2;})
    .select([](int i){ return i * i;})
    ;

    for (auto obj : r)
    {
        std::cout << obj << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I don't know enough C++ to really answer your questions though (I'm much more of a C and C# guy!)

Comment: I thought Linq failed as a DB extraction (or is now considered horrible). Could be wrong.

Comment: There is framework to convert linq expression to query. But I am refer to linq style functional approach to process list here. My code have nothing to do with DB.

Comment: If you're just looking for this sort of capability, see http://cpplinq.codeplex.com/ - even if you want to write your own it may still be worth looking at some of the decisions they made (such as `operator>>` instead of dot-methods to enhance extensibility).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is a good idea (nor do I think the cpplinq in @MichaelUrman's post is a good idea - though it's definitely workable).

Basically you are writing a fully templated hierarchy of classes, to replace (existing, stable and presumably tested) functionality in std algorithm:

Your code:

```
auto r =
linq::range(1, 30)
.where([](int i){ return i % 2;})
.select([](int i){ return i * i;})
;

for (auto obj : r)
{
    std::cout << obj << "\n";
}
```

std code:

```
std::vector<int> src{1, /**/, 29};
std::vector<int> x;
std::copy_if(src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(x), [](int i){ return i % 2;});
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](int i){ return i * i;});
```

You could create your own `transform_if`, combining the two functions above.

Comment: Yes I agree the functionality are similar and performance of std algorithm is definitely better. but don't you think my way is easier to read/write? and my iterators are lazy evaluated so if I only need first N objects I only have to evaluate functors in `select`/`where` for first N objects. Maybe there is way to do this with std library but I don't know about it.