# Making C++11 range-based for loops a bit more useful

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 is great. Probably one of the most beautiful features (in my opinion) is the so-called range-based-for-loop.
Instead of

```
for ( std::size_t i(0); i < range.size(); ++i )
{
   // do something to range[i];
}
```

or

```
for ( Range::iterator it(range.begin()); it != range.end(); ++it )
{
   // do something to *it;
}
```

or simplified with C++11 auto:

```
for ( auto it(range.begin()); it != range.end(); ++it )
{
   // do something to *it;
}
```

we can say this:

```
for ( auto& entry : range )
{
   // do something with entry.
}
```

This is very expressive: We talk about the entry, rather than the i^th position in the range or the iterator pointing to an entry. However, this syntax lacks the ability of having subranges (e.g. ignoring the last entry). In a series of small helper structs / methods, I want to add this functionality in a clean way.

So much for my motivation ;-) Now, for the real deal.

In this post, I address conditions on the entries of `range`. Basically, the helper code should perform the equivalent of

```
for ( auto& entry : range )
{
   if ( condition(entry) )
   {
       // do something to entry.
   }
}
```

but without that level of indentation.

Here is the code for ConditionalRange:

```
template <typename Range, typename Runnable>
ConditionalRange<Range, Runnable> makeConditionalRange(Range& range, Runnable&& condition)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(condition(*std::declval<Range>().begin())), bool>::value, "Condition must return a boolean value.");
   return ConditionalRange<Range, Runnable>(range, std::forward<Runnable>(condition));
}

template <typename Range, typename Runnable>
struct ConditionalRange
{
   public:
      friend ConditionalRange makeConditionalRange<>(Range&, Runnable&&);
   public:
      using iterator_type = ConditionalIterator<decltype(std::declval<Range>().begin()), Runnable>;
      iterator_type begin() const
      {
         auto b = range.begin();
         while ( b != range.end() && !condition(*b) )
         {
            ++b;
         }
         return ConditionalIterator<decltype(std::declval<Range>().begin()), Runnable>(b, range.end(), condition);
      }
      iterator_type end() const
      {
         return ConditionalIterator<decltype(std::declval<Range>().begin()), Runnable>(range.end(), range.end(), condition);
      }
   private:
      ConditionalRange(Range& range_, Runnable&& condition_)
      :
         range(range_),
         condition(std::forward<Runnable>(condition_))
      {
      }
   private:
      Range& range;
      Runnable condition;
};
```

This is the helper struct for the iterator:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Runnable>
struct ConditionalIterator
{
   private:
      Iterator iterator;
      Iterator end;
      const Runnable& condition;
   public:
      ConditionalIterator(Iterator b, Iterator e, const Runnable& r)
      :
         iterator(b),
         end(e),
         condition(r)
      {
      }
      auto operator*() -> decltype(*iterator)
      {
         return *iterator;
      }
      ConditionalIterator& operator++()
      {
         do
         {
            ++iterator;
         }
         while ( iterator != end && !condition(*iterator) );
         return *this;
      }
      bool operator==(const ConditionalIterator& second)
      {
         return iterator == second.iterator;
      }
      bool operator!=(const ConditionalIterator& second)
      {
         return !(*this == second);
      }
};
```

The intended usage is:

```
std::vector<int> ns{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
for ( const auto& n : makeConditionalRange(ns, [](int a) { return a % 2 == 0; }) )
{
   std::cout << n << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Demo: [click here!](http://ideone.com/XCgCny)

What are weaknesses of my approach? With what kind of arguments does it fail, although it shouldn't in the perfect world?

Comment: I can see no weaknesses, but I think you should consider renaming makeConditionalRange with something that focuses on client code appearance, not on "making a conditional range". By that, I mean that client code should look like this instead: `for(const auto& n: iterate_if(ns, [](int a) { return a % 2 == 0; }) )`

Comment: So does the intent here differ significantly from a Boost [`filter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)?

Comment: @JerryCoffin No it doesn't. I simply haven't looked into Boost ;-)

Comment: Also potentially interesting: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35997/c-linq-like-library

Comment: @stefan: Since boost is the proving ground for libraries before they move into the standard. You should probably start using boost.

Comment: The most common test for iterators `operator!=` optimize this over `operator==`

Comment: @LokiAstari Sure, operator!= is more common. But I guess the compiler is smart enough to perform this optimization. After all, it's inline-able. Concerning boost: I'm not a big fan. I'm much more a fan of having a small set of self-written helpers for which I can guarantee correctness. I don't want to rely on another library for which there are several versions.

Comment: @stefan: To be blunt that's silly. Its like saying I don't wont to buy a car from the standard manufacturers because I want to build one that runs off seaweed myself to guarantee that it does not cause pollution. The problem is your set of libraries are going to be infinitely more buggy than boost because you only have one set of eyes looking at them. Boost has thousands of people checking and validating the code fixing and providing feedback to make sure the correct idioms are used correctly. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149305/14065

Comment: @stefan: Additionally. Its worth watching because the next set of additions to `ST2` will be coming from boost. So you have to learn about that anyway if you want to stay up to date on the standard library.

Answer (score 10):

You can use braces to return from your functions. That way, you won't have to repeat long and cumbersome types (DRY, as much as possible). For example, `ConditionalRange::end`:

```
iterator_type end() const
{
    return { range.end(), range.end(), condition };
}
```

Also, you probably want your function to accept C-style arrays too. Therefore, you should use `std::begin` and `std::end` instead of calling the member functions:

```
iterator_type end() const
{
    return { std::end(range), std::end(range), condition };
}
```

With that (everywhere in your code) and some trivial changes, your code will also work for C-style arrays (tested [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c86df29b547c6267) and it works fine).

### Naming your function

The name `makeConditionalRange` is quite long. The function you created already exists in other libraries and programming languages (Python comes to my mind) under the name `filter`. You should consider changing its name in order for many users to recognize the name at first glance (moreover, it will be shorter).